# How to programmatically take screenshot of root view and set it back as background of that layout in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot

I need to take the screenshot of the main layout of my activity and again set it as the background of that layout. I am using the following code for it.

```
Bitmap bitmap;
       View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
       v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
       v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

the following code is using to set it as background

```
Drawable dr=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                        mLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
```

But When I set it the image slides downward. I mean it shrinks downwards everytime on taking screenshot and setting back. Can anyone tell me the issue.

Please suggest with some sample code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little change made it happen.

```
Bitmap bitmap;
       View v1 = RootView;
       v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
       v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```